# Next.js SEO not appearing in google search deployed to vercel

Tags: seo

I recently starting working with next.js to create a SEO friendly Website. I deployed it with vercel but none of my SEO is showing up in google when I search for the website URL.

This is my home page which I've done SEO work too

```
import Head from 'next/head'
import React from 'react';


function HomePage() {
  return (
    <div className="mainHomePage"> 
      <Head>
        <meta charSet="UTF-8"/>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, inital-scale=1.0"/>
        <meta httpEquiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge,chrome=1"/>
        <title>Digital Marketing & Media Agency | Calgary | Morissette Technologies Inc</title>
        <meta name="description" content="Results-driven Media and Marketing Agency based in Calgary with a focus on Digital Marketing, Web Design, SEO services and Social Media."/>
        <meta name="keywords" content="Web Development, Web Design, Digital Marketing, Online Markting, SEO, SEM, Social Media Marketing, Social Media"/>
        <meta name="author" content="Cristof Morissette"/>
      </Head>
      <div className="homeContainer">
        <h1 className="homeTitle">Hello, we are<a className="homeName"> Morissette Media</a>.</h1>
        <a className="HomeAnchor" href="/about"><p className="homeButtonText">View my work</p></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default HomePage;
```

This is my package.json

```
"name": "cristof-website2.0",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "proxy": "https://nameless-sands-69882.herokuapp.com",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next",
    "build": "next build && next export",
    "start": "next start"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.20.0",
    "cross-env": "^7.0.2",
    "next": "9.5.5",
    "next-videos": "1.4.0",
    "nextjs-sitemap-generator": "^1.1.0",
    "react": "16.14.0",
    "react-dom": "16.14.0",
    "react-icons": "^3.11.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "reactstrap": "^8.6.0",
    "yarn": "^1.22.10"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "webpack": "^5.2.0"
  }
}
```

When I inspect my home page I can see the meta tags I created in the head of the project but it's not being reflected in google when I search for my website. I used the vercel CLI to deploy what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you submitted your site to google?

Comment: It's deployed and I have put it through the google search console is that what you're referring too?

Comment: Did you submit a sitemap?